# Null pointer struggling for weeks

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

this code is giving me a null pointer please help me fix it.

```
private void homeFragment(Profile profile) {
    if (profile != null) {
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putParcelable(PARCEL_KEY, profile);
        HomeFragment hf = new HomeFragment();
        hf.setArguments(mBundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); is the line the logcat is pointing me to please help

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: What is the exception stack trace

Comment: when are you calling this method? maybe getActivity() is returning null

Comment: Weeks?  How is that possible?  The stack trace tells you the file and the line at which it happens.  A spin through a debugger will tell you what you missed in five minutes.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference

Comment: getActivity() is returning null

Comment: when are you calling this method?

Comment: getActivity is coming as null. Pls check if this fragment is being called by activity or not.

Comment: getActivity does not appear anywhere else in my code, only just here on this line

Comment: @duffymo im not sure how to Spin through a debbuger, please assist

Comment: You need an IDE.  IntelliJ is the best; use Eclipse or NetBeans if you must.

Comment: Not forgetting Android Studio, which Google recommend. By the way I answered you question ;O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are writing should be in a class similar to this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class YourFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Then `getSupportFragmentManager()` is visible without `getActivity()`, e.g.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, mBullet_frag).commit();
```

You must include the v4 library in the final build (just find it in the sdk and drop it in your project libs folder).

This will work, if you follow all the rules.

Of course it could be you did not intend to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` but wanted the standard one (`getFragmentManager()`). In this case you don't need the v4 library, or reference to it.